# Как узнать информацию о компьютере с Python?

Tags: python

Хочу в базе сохранять информацию о пользователях, которые запускают программу. Но какой уникальное значение использовать? Операционная система - не вариант, windows или linux установлен у тысяч, это как уникальный id не подходит. Какую информацию о компьютере пользователя можно получить с помощью python (в плане разрешённого), которая была бы уникальным для каждого компьютера?
Информация, которая была бы уникальным для каждого пользователя и хранилась в базе данных.
Библиотека platform не помогает в этом случае:

```
import platform
import socket

my_system = platform.uname()

print(f"System: {my_system.system}")
print(f"Release: {my_system.release}")
print(f"Node Name: {my_system.node}")
print(f"Version: {my_system.version}")
print(f"Machine: {my_system.machine}")
print(f"Processor: {my_system.processor}")
```

```
System: Windows
Release: 10
....
```

Comment: Просто сгенерируйте свой собственный случайный идентификатор и не мудрите, например?

Comment: @andreymal а если пользователь закроет программу и запустит еще раз, как сохранится этот его уникальный id? Если его id есть уже в базе, не хотелось бы опять пихать еще один (получается уже 2 id на одного пользователя)

Comment: Ну сохраните куда-нибудь на компьютере пользователя, в файл, в реестр или любое другое удобное место, при следующем запуске считывайте

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! Опубликуйте этот как ответ, чтобы можно было закрыть вопрос

Comment: Можно к MAC адресу сетевух привязаться (да, я знаю, что их много где можно менять).

Answer (score 0):

предлагаю использовать mac адрес. и обязательно шифровать. например: берем мас адрес компьютера Х и генерируем контрольную сумму sha. это и будет id. т.е. пишешь, чтобы клиент в бд отпраалял не мас, так как эта инфа конфиденциальная, а чексум.

Comment: Во-первых, MAC-адрес поменяется при смене сетевой карты, а иногда он даже просто через настройки меняется. Во-вторых, разнообразие MAC-адресов очень маленькое (всего 6 байт на адрес, а с учётом ограниченного числа производителей — даже ещё меньше), а значит по чексуммме можно будет очень быстро восстановить исходный MAC-адрес и получить нарушение конфиденциальности

Comment: Наверное сохранять хэш MAC-адреса вместо адреса нет особого смысла, поскольку количество адресов ограничено и их можно перебрать за приемлемое время, восстановив таким образом значение MAC-адреса.